# Cytoscape define edge length

Tags: cytoscape

I am creating a manual layout for a network in Cytoscape version 3.8.2. I would like to be able to define the edge lengths, so the network looks more uniform. Is there a way to define the property edge length?

Specifically, I want something like the below subsection of a network  to be a perfect circle.

[image: this subsection of a network]

Answer (score 0):

No, the edge length is not a property in Cytoscape.  You would need to calculate it based on the source and target node positions.  One way to achieve what you want would be select all of the outer nodes, then do a degree-sorted circular layout, and then drag your central node back into the center.

-- scooter